# more components connected to redux or less? react

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Is it better to have:

1. More components connected to redux? or
2. Less components connected to redux, so more props are passed down from parent to children components?

Which if more performant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the use case but most of the time more components connected to redux state is the better approach.

Ex Consider you have a `ParentComponent` having two child components `ChildComponentOne` and `ChildComponentTwo` and my use case is that I wanted to update my `ChildComponentOne` only on my redux state update

```
    class ParentComponent extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
          <View>
           <ChildComponentOne/> 
           <ChildComponentTwo/> 

           <AnotherComponents>
          </View>
        );
      }
    }
```

If my redux state (which contains state data for `ChildComponentOne` only) is connected to a `ParentComponent` then `ChildComponentOne` and `ChileComponentTwo` both will get re-render with `ParentCopmponents` `AnotherComponents` elements.

Now If my redux state (which contains state data for `ChildComponentOne` only) directly to the `ChildComponenOne` only then only that components means `ChildComponentOne` will get updated and other components such as `ParentComponent`, `ChildComponentTwo` and `AnotherComponent` in the parent will not re-render.